# Field equal 1 display

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I would like to only get the activityCode for the orderno when it equals 1 if there are duplicate orderno with the activityCode equals 0.
Also, if the record for orderno activityCode equals 0 then display those records also. But I would only like to display the orderno when the activityCode equals 0 if the same orderno activityCode does not equal 1 or the activityCode only equals 0. I hope this is clear and makes sense but let me know if I need to provide more details. Thanks

--create table

```
create table po_v  
(   
  orderno int,   
  amount number,   
  activityCode number    
)
```

--insert values

```
insert into po_v values     
(170268, 2774.31, 0),    
(17001988, 288.82, 0),    
(17001988, 433.23, 1),    
(170271, 3786, 1),    
(170271, 8476, 0),    
(170055, 34567, 0)
```

--Results

```
170268    | 2774.31 | 0    
17001988  | 433.23  | 1    
170271    | 3786    | 1     
170055    | 34567   | 0
```

*****Updated*****
I have inserted two new records and the results have been updated. The data in the actual table has other numbers besides 0 and 1. The select statement displays the correct orderno's but I would like the other records for the orderno to display also. The partition only populates one record per orderno. If possible I would like to see the records with the same activityCode.

--insert values

```
insert into po_v values      
(170271, 3799, 1),    
(172525, 44445, 2)

    --select statement
    SELECT Orderno, 
    Amount, 
    Activitycode 
    FROM   (SELECT orderno, 
           amount, 
           activitycode, 
           ROW_NUMBER() 
             OVER( 
               PARTITION BY orderno 
               ORDER BY  activitycode DESC) AS dup 
    FROM   Po_v)dt 
    WHERE  dt.dup = 1 
    ORDER  BY 1
```

--select statement results

```
170055    | 34567   | 0
170268    | 2774.31 | 0    
170271    | 3786    | 1 
172525    | 44445   | 2
17001988  | 433.23  | 1
```

--expected results

```
170055    | 34567   | 0
170268    | 2774.31 | 0    
170271    | 3786    | 1 
170271    | 3799    | 1 
172525    | 44445   | 2
17001988  | 433.23  | 1
```

Comment: You know you're only about a year away from end of life for the Sql Server 2008 product, right? After that date, it will no longer get updates... not even critical security patches. Time to start thinking about replacing or upgrading this server.

Comment: The activityCode value should be only 0 or 1? Any other values?

Comment: Hello Joel, yes it is time to think about upgrading this server.

Comment: Hello EricZ, The only values will be 0 and 1 for the activityCode.

Comment: Not sure why this has downvotes. The OP posted table definition (albeit with invalid datatypes), sample data and desired output. They did pretty much all the things needed for a question to be good. Some people around here don't really want to help, they just want to hand out downvotes silently.

Comment: @CharlesCarter, you should go with Sean's answer, I was going to post the same code

Comment: @SeanLange when I hover my mouse over the downvote button, the first sentence in the tooltip is "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @TabAlleman I agree. But as you know it is often challenging because the person doesn't know what to search for. Sure this has been asked and answered hundreds of times but perhaps the OP learned something today.

Comment: I definitely understand, I am sorry for not providing more research. I usually am in the Toad for Oracle environment so this SQL Server is newer to me. Not sure but I am learning and appreciate all of the assistance and knowledge here. I will definitely provide more information for my next post. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Orderno, 
       Amount, 
       Activitycode 
FROM   (SELECT orderno, 
               amount, 
               activitycode, 
               ROW_NUMBER() 
                 OVER( 
                   PARTITION BY orderno 
                   ORDER BY  activitycode DESC) AS dup 
        FROM   Po_v)dt 
WHERE  dt.dup = 1 
ORDER  BY 1
```

Result

```
Orderno     Amount      Activitycode
------------------------------------
170055      34567.00       0
170268      2774.31        0
170271      3786.00        1
17001988    433.23         1
```

Comment: @SeanLange i will follow your suggestions bro

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange

Answer (score 1):

Not totally clear what you are trying to do here but this returns the output you are expecting.

```
select orderno
    , amount
    , activityCode
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by orderno order by activityCode desc)
    from po_v
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

**---EDIT---**

With the new details this is a very different question. As I understand it now you want all row for that share the max activity code for each orderno. You can do this pretty easily with a cte.

```
with MyGroups as
(
    select orderno
        , Activitycode = max(activitycode)
    from po_v
    group by orderno
)
select *
from po_v p
join MyGroups g on g.orderno = p.orderno 
    and g.Activitycode = p.Activitycode
```

Comment: I added some more logic to this post, if you can review the *****Updated***** portion that would be great. Thanks!